# Set default image for woocommerce products

Tags: woocommerce, product

In my project I have many products whose image is not available till now. So I want to show custom image for those products who don't have image.

Is there a way to set default image for products (in case if product don't have image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding following code in `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_fix_thumbnail' );

function custom_fix_thumbnail() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src', 'custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src');

    function custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src( $src ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $uploads = untrailingslashit( $upload_dir['baseurl'] );
        $src = $uploads . '/2012/07/thumb1.jpg';

        return $src;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : Do not type complete url of image. Instead of complete url, use only short url as shown in code.
[Original Post](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-the-placeholder-image/)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
You need to upload an image via default Wordpress Media uploader, then copy its URL (or just ID) and paste it to "WooCommerce->Settings->Products->Placeholder image"

Found an answer here: https://www.iqcomputing.com/support/articles/changing-the-woocommerce-default-image/